# Smoothness of function and finite difference method for computing its (first) derivative

Tags: derivatives

I wonder whether a finite difference method for computing the first derivative of function, just needs that it belongs to (differentiability) class $C^{1}$. But I read that for case of central difference difference, the function should belong to, at least, $C^{2}$. Is it true?

Comment: Where did you read that?  Link?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order of derivation in Taylor series approximation. If you use  centered differential formula for 2nd derivatives, of course the function should be of class $C^2$.